# cannot resolve symbol mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

recent i try to apply dbscan-on-spark from https://github.com/irvingc/dbscan-on-spark

i imported libraryDependencies to build.sbt as below but i still get error "cannot resolve symbol mllib" when i import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.dbscan.DBSCAN, any expert can advise me on this?

```
name := "DB_Oracle_V09"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark" % "5.0.0-alpha4"

resolvers += "bintray/irvingc" at "http://dl.bintray.com/irvingc/maven"
libraryDependencies += "com.irvingc.spark" %% "dbscan" % "0.1.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.2.0"

resolvers += "bintray/irvingc" at "http://dl.bintray.com/irvingc/maven"
libraryDependencies += "com.irvingc.spark" %% "dbscan" % "0.1.0"
```

Comment: That project you are linking to is dead. I've contributed to it once but the repo owner doesn't seem to be working on it anymore. It might work for spark 2.1 but that's about it...

Comment: Plus, your spark dependencies don't match. You can't have 2.2 and 2.4 at the same time...

Comment: thanks for your reply, if i change all to 2.4, will it solve "cannot resolve symbol mllib"  problem?

Comment: i am still getting "cannot resolve symbol mllib" after i changed all to 2.4.....

Comment: i solved this problem after i add below reference in sbt
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.3.0"